# How to validate a file input path? - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Below query helps to validate when I keep invalid path. The problem is its failing when I enter " \ " or "." or any special characters. How to validate them?

```
FILE-INFO:FILENAME = "\".

IF FILE-INFO:FULL-PATHNAME = "?" THEN
  MESSAGE "Invalid path".
```

Comment: Please explain "failing". But you definitively want to remove the quotes around the ?. ? is the unknown value - "?" is the character value with the question mark as text.

Answer (score 3):

The "\" is an "escape" character on UNIX so that could certainly be a problem. Either double-escape it as "\\" or alternate-escape it with "~".

Mike's point about ? vs "?" is also spot-on.

In other words:

```
FILE-INFO:FILENAME = "~\".

IF FILE-INFO:FULL-PATHNAME = ? THEN
  MESSAGE "Invalid path".
```

Also - for portability reasons it is better to use forward slashes as directory separators. They work for either Windows or UNIX whereas backslash will only work if your code runs on Windows.

Comment: Almost, Tom. Backslash is an escape character on Linux. On Windows it's just a regular character.

Comment: Good point, I'll update.

Comment: You can use forward slash instead. Also on Windows. Something @TomBascom has told me in another question.